# opencart 2.0 запись на базу

Tags: запрос, opencart

Дорогие гуру opencart помогите с вопросом. Как сделать в своем контролере запрос к базу на запись, удаления, обновления, не как не могу понят.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Легко! Открываем исходный код любого контроллера и читаем. В кратце:
в OpenCart используется принцип MVC, то есть логика работы разделена на части. В контроллере обрабатываются данные, получение/запись данных в модели, ну а с помощью вьюх данные отображаются.
Допустим сделали Мы контроллер `controller/catalog/ctrl.php`, тогда желательно сделать и модель `model/catalog/ctrl.php`.
В модели делаем запросы, а в контроллере обрабатываем результаты запросов.
Контроллер:

```
$this->load->model('catalog/ctrl');
$results = $this->model_catalog_ctrl->getRes();
```

Или так:

```
$this->load->model('catalog/ctrl');
$this->model_catalog_ctrl->delRes();
```

Модель:

```
public function getRes() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->rows;
}
```

Или так:

```
public function delRes() {
    $this->db->query("DELETE * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "")
}
```

Comment: а `insert` хде??? и еще было круто привести пример с передачей параметров

Comment: М-м-м, это сарказм или правда примеры нужны? Открыв любой контроллер OC можно увидеть примеры на все случаи.

Comment: не сарказм, правда хотелось бы увидеть, есть проект на opencart, мне бы было полезно знать это, я аж плюсанул

Comment: Не хотел обидеть, просто показалось. Для примеров расписывать много, гораздо проще изучать глядя в код [Github](https://github.com/opencart/opencart) . Даже файловая структура и названия функций "говорящие", надо только в них разобраться хорошенько. Для начала, хорошо расписано [здесь](http://forum.opencart-russia.ru/threads/rukovodstvo-razrabotchika.14/)